# svnkit, list all files of an SVN repository, without checking out the files

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

svnkit.com is an [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) library in Java. For instance, you can get the log of an SVN repository as follows:

```
SVNClientManager.newInstance().getLogClient();
SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNURL url, String[] paths, SVNRevision pegRevision, SVNRevision startRevision, SVNRevision endRevision, boolean stopOnCopy, boolean discoverChangedPaths,
            boolean includeMergedRevisions, long limit, String[] revisionProperties, final ISVNLogEntryHandler handler);
```

How do I list all files of an SVN repository (without checking out the files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `SvnList`. For an example on how to use, have a look at `org.tmatesoft.svn.test.ListTest#testListOnRepositoryRoot` et al. as it is present in the latest revision of the 1.7.x branch in the [SVNKit repository](http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit).