# How to get the directory size of a SVN repository using SVN Java API.

Tags: java, svn, svn-api

I am trying to get the SVN repository info using SVN Java API. Now i need to get the size of each directory at any level. I checked in the [DOC](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/index.html) and find inside the class **SVNDirEntry** there is a method **getSize()** which is applicable only when the entry node is a file.

can someone please help me to find out the size of a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like your filesystem. A directory has no "size" in and of itself (well, technically a few bytes are taken on disk for recordkeeping, but that's not the point) - it's just an organizational marker. The "size" of a directory is the sum of the sizes of the files contained in the directory.

So, to get the size of a directory, you will need to enumerate all the files, get their sizes, and sum them.

Comment: The size of a folder -might- also be the number of files and subdirectories in it. It all depends on context. It would be interesting for the OP to share exactly for what purpose the size is needed.

Comment: @Gimby : U r correct. i need the size of files and subdirectories for a directory. Actually i have a web app where i m showing the directory structure of a repository in a tree view. so now the requirement is lyk if a user select a very large repo or any directory in it, then i hv to show a alert. therefore to determine the size of a repo or any directory in it at each level.

Comment: @alroc : could you please provide a solution on how to enumerate all the files including their subdirectories, get their sizes, and sum them.

Comment: @angel it starts with googling for "svnkit list files" and then you would easily find this existing thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316098/svnkit-list-all-files-of-a-svn-repository-without-checking-out-the-files

Comment: @angel, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. If you have specific questions about what to do after you've started and gotten stuck, post those as a separate question.